# use genetic algorithm as a feature selection for text classification

Tags: feature-selection, text-classification, genetic-algorithms

how to apply the genetic algorithm as a feature selection for text classification  in python
I need to use GA to select most relevant feature in text classification

Comment: have a look at TPOT https://epistasislab.github.io/tpot/

Comment: does it used as feature selection there??

Comment: In the original paper they talk about it https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.06212.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There's a python library that helps do this task. TextFeatureSelection is the library and TextFeatureSelectionGA is the module.

https://pypi.org/project/TextFeatureSelection/